# How to solve the import path "context" error in the docker

Tags: docker

I'm installing a docker project from github and there are commands given in the repository and I'm just following them. The project is almost download but it gives an error while downloading the `RUN go get github.com/gorilla/mux` In my system I have go version 1.10

Git Repository:- https://github.com/mmorejon/microservices-docker-go-mongodb

Error:-

> package context: unrecognized import path "context" (import path does not begin with hostname)

Can any one please tell how this error be solved.

Answer (score 0):

The package context is only available in `go versions 1.7` and after you should check all the dockerfiles in your specified folders example `microservices-docker-go-mongodb-master` in your mentioned link and change FROM

```
golang:1.6 to golang:1.7
```

or any version you need to specify. Next, you have to change the port of the db in file `docker-compose.yml`

example:-

```
image: mongo:3.3
container_name: cinema-db
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
volumes:
  - ./backup:/backup:rw
```

to

```
ports:
- "27018:27018"
```

because,you already installed mongodb `27017` you have to change it.